# D3.js Horizontal Bar Graph - Change Bar Direction (left to right instead of right to left)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have a horizontal bar graph as shown below:[image]

I know it's an easy fix I just can't seem to find where to change the drawing of the bar from left side to right side instead of right side to left side.

Comment: The upperleft of your svg element is (0,0) in x,y. So when you want to change the starting value, you need to change the coordinate position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line 64 from

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x (d.values); })
```

to

```
.attr("x", 0)
```

since that is what sets the x position of the bar.

EDIT: Ah, so what you want is actually to fill the negative space, instead, so you also wanted to change the length of the bars. If you want to change the width, modify the width attribute.

```
    .attr("width", function(d) { return width - x(d.values); });
```

should be

```
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.values); });
```

Comment: That made the bars the opposite length than they should be. I also had to change var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]); to var x = d3.scale.linear().range([width, 0]);. Thanks for the help

Comment: Actually, when I made that second change it reversed the order of the x axis

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that you wanted to change the widths as well from the question. Seemed like you just wanted them drawn from the other side. Edited.